# About C++ template and explicit declaration

Tags: c++, c++11

I just spent about an 20 minutes trying to figure out why some template methods of mine passed compilation but not linkage.

Turns out I needed to explicitly declare my template method.

It was something of this kind :

```
class Test {
   template<class Source> void Save(Source& obj);
};
```

Then I would use it like this somewhere :

```
Test t;
ClassDerivedFromInterface obj;
t.Save(obj);
```

It compiled fine but didn't link. Until I added :

```
template void Test::Save(ClassDerivedFromInterface);
```

I would like to understand in which case an explicit declaration is necessary.

Thanks

Comment: were `t.Save(obj);` and `template void Test::Save(ClassDerivedFromInterface);` in the same file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell, you need to have the entire body (the *definition*) of a template function visible to the translation unit that instantiates the template. So when you say `t.Save(obj);`, that translation unit should have access to the definition of `Save`. Usually you achieve this by including the definitions of function templates in the header file itself.

The reason for this is that templates aren't ordinary code that gets compiled and can later be linked at will. Rather, templates are a *code generation* tool that generates the necessary code on demand - an automatic version of copy/paste followed by search-and-replace, if you will.

Therefore, the actual compilable code for your function `Save(ClassDerivedFromInterface&)` doesn't come into existence until you write that line. If only the declaration of the function template is visible, then the template only produces the declaration of the concrete function, but not its body, and so at link time you notice that the function is missing.

To recap, templates themselves cannot be compiled, it is only their concrete instances that can, and you have to pay attention to ensure that the concrete instances are always available when you instantiate them. Explicit instantiation as you have it works and allows you to package a few specific instances into a separate TU, but generally that's hard to maintain and not scalable, and there are other drawbacks to explicit instantiation that you avoid when you let the compiler instantiate implicitly. So usually it's best to package your entire definitions into the header file.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I find it quite normal now that I have an idea of how template works.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to explicitly declare the template if the template source is not visible at the time of compilation. This link covers it pretty well, also an awesome site in general:

[C++ FAQ 35.13](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.13)

Answer (score 2):

You need explicit declaration when your template definitions are not accesible from the code that is using them, consider the following:

```
template.h - template declarations
template.cpp - template definitions
main.cpp - template usage
```

`template.cpp` is not included in `main.cpp` and thus unreachable by the template user so you need explicit declarations.
But if your structure is:

```
template.h - template declarations and definitions
main.cpp - template usage
```

the template declarations are reachable by the template user so you don't need explicit declarations.

Comment: Note there is an "export" keyword depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler needs to know what types you're going to be using with your template. If you create a template class and then use it with, for example, `int`, `char`, and `double`, then the compiler will create methods for the template for those types. If you compile the template method in a separate compilation unit from where you use it, the compiler will not instantiate your template for the type you need. But if you explicitly instantiate the template, the compiler will create whatever you tell it to.